# Date format changes after the 240th Row in Date Column of CSV: goes from 1880-01-15 (%Y-%m-%d) to 15-01-00 (%d-%m-%y). How do I make them the same?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, python-datetime

I need to be able to change the following dates in new_file["Date] from 15,01,00 (%d,%m,%y) format to 1880-01-15 (%Y-%m-%d) format so that the column is completely uniform. The formats change at the 240th index of the column.

[[image: Example of different date format]]

Here is my following attempt. Can someone help me?

```
from datetime import date, datetime 
import pandas as pd


file = pd.read_csv("sea_levels_1880_2015.csv")
#print(file)

#converting data frame to csv
headerList = ["Date", "Global_Mean_Sea_Level", "GMSL_Uncertainty"]
file.to_csv("sea_lvl_1880_2015.csv", header=headerList, index=False)

# display modified csv file
new_file = pd.read_csv("sea_lvl_1880_2015.csv")

#changing format from 15,01,00 to 15-01-00
new_file['Date'] = new_file['Date'].str.replace(',','-')

#new_file['Date'] = pd.to_datetime( "%Y-%m-%d")

print(new_file)
```

Comment: "15,01,00" does not mean January 2015.  It means January 15, 1900.  EXACTLY what format is that column in your CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- on your example each date represent seperate month,
- for some reason dates after hitting 1900 moved to 15th of each month instead of 1st, like it was in 1800s (or you cut the last 5 when preparing the example),
- your data doesn't go over 1999,

This should solve your problem:

```
new_file['Date'] = new_file['Date'].str.replace(r'(\d\d),(\d\d),(\d\d)', r'19\3-\2-\1', regex=True)
```

If you want to just keep it in the file and not do any date operations, you don't really need to import anything from datetime.

I hope that helps.